# Can a delegate of a closure be a closure?

Tags: groovy, closures

I am trying to read/update some variables of one closure in another closure.

I set define two variables in closure `a` and read/update it in closure `b` but Groovy cannot find the variables:

```
Closure a = {
  String var1 = "var1"
  String var2 = "var2"
}

Closure b = {
  var2 = "new var2"
  println(var1)
  println(var2)
}

b.delegate = a
b()
```

How can closure `b` get access to those two variables? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can. You can't get the variables from outside, like `a.var1` won't work either

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate a closure from **map** like class object instead of trying to delegate to another closure. **If you know already, Please ignore**

Like shown below code :

```
Map binding = [a: "Legion Commander", b : "wind ranger"]
Closure test = { a = "Invoker"; println "My favs : $a , $b"}
test.delegate = binding
test()
```